# Understanding the history and construction of beeja mantra

Tags: mantras, tantra

Surely TM is not the only one to use beeja mantra, and sages probably was using them since time unknown.

The philosophy behind agyamya, nigyama and mantras was that to make it available to all and without question get the benefits. In those days, people will give their all to their gurus, accept them as the incarnation of god and learn from them.

The other guru that is mentioned in the Vedic text is the intuition of the own self.

In this present times, where people are either charging ridiculous amount to just teach a beeja mantra or a fake guru, initiating you and wasting your time and effort, I was wondering if there is any way to learn the basic grammar behind beeja mantra and construct the one that suits the need !

Comment: Formatted for increasing the readability please

Comment: As far as I understood,  while imparting appropriate bija to the disciple,  a true Guru will transmit his/her power also, to activate certain yogic spots.  If activation is not done,  recitation of bija will result in nAma japa only.  That's where the importance of Guru lies

Comment: What do you mean by yogic spots?

Comment: Certain nerve centres, capable of releasing energy

Comment: Well composed question! Indeed there is way to do it by reading some specific Tantrik books. But it is advised to learn from a Guru only. Also It is not that only fake Gurus are there. True and competent Gurus are there too who can teach all these to deserving disciples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Shiva Sutras by Jaideva Singh](http://bibleoteca.narod.ru/tantra/Jaideva_Singh_Siva_Sutras.pdf), **Section II(comprises of 10 Sutras)** greatly deals with mantras, mudras and science, etymology behind it.

The very first Sutras says:

> Cittam mantrah.
>
> चित्तम् in this context means that by which the Highest
>   Reality is cognised.
>
> **मन्त्रः a formula consisting of a word or a set of words addressed to a deity.**
>
> "By intensive awareness of one's identity with **the Highest
>   Reality enshrined in a mantra and thus becoming identical with
>   that Reality the mind itself becomes mantra."**

From the commentary of first Sutra, few terms explained further in Note section:

**prasāda and praṇava;**

*prasāda* which is a technical word of this system which will not
be found in any dictionary. It is the name of the mantra **sauh(सौः)**. It contains within itself the entire panorama of manifestation. It represents all
the 36 tattvas.

*praṇava* is the mystic sacred syllable. According to
Saivagama, there are four kinds of pranava,

(1) the Saiva Pranava which is  **हुं(huṃ)**

(2) the Sakta pranava which is **क्लीं(klīṃ)**

(3) the maya pranava which is **ह्रीं(hrīṃ)** and

(4) the Vedic pranava which is **ॐ(oṃ)**

The pranava referred to in this sutra is the Saiva-pranava.

[From same book, Page 89](http://bibleoteca.narod.ru/tantra/Jaideva_Singh_Siva_Sutras.pdf):  As has been said in Tantrasadbhava:

> "O dear one, **all mantras consist of letters. The letters are a
>   form of sakti.** That sakti should be known as matrka. Matrka
>   should be known as the very form of Siva."

[From the same book, page 111](http://bibleoteca.narod.ru/tantra/Jaideva_Singh_Siva_Sutras.pdf), a table described the letters with associated shaktis and tattvas:

[image]

I cherry picked some of the content from the book, So I would suggest to read this section II, that will give understanding how mantras and beejakshara are formed. Though this section describe it very well, but it is advised to receive this knowledge from a Guru himself.

Also to know the history of Shiva Sutras, refer this answer: [What is the story of revelation of Shiva sutras to sage Sri Vasugupta?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24965/647)

Comment: With the mention bija given for Saiva Pranava is missing an a after H and before U :)))

Comment: @user3344236 It's in devanagari, I'll add the transliteration.

Comment: I know is devanagari, but not hum stands for Shiva pranava. It is haum which is Prasada Bija also. I did not found references  for Kurccha Bija or other forms of hum for Shiva, but prasada indeed :)

Comment: @user3344236 Could you tell me the reference of whatever you said? In Shiva Sutras it is  hum and not haum.