# How are different beeja presented to world?

Tags: scripture, mantras

We may look at various beeja like 'gam' or the 'paraprasad' beeja etc. These are presented in verses with much secrecy such that, even though we read it or say it to someone the actual form of beeja remains hidden.
For example:

> गणादिं पूर्वमुच्चार्य वर्णादींस्तदनन्तरम् । अनुस्वारः परतरः ।
> अर्धेन्दुलसितम् । तारेण ऋद्धम् । एतत्तव मनुस्वरूपम्

This is where the Ganapati beej ' om gam' is found.

Take another example from Kulavarna tantra:

> अनन्तचन्द्रभुवनमिन्दुबिन्दुयुगान्वित: । श्रीप्रासादपरामन्त्रो
> भुक्तिमुक्तिफलप्रद पराप्रासादमन्त्रस्तु सादिरुक्त:कुलेश्वारि ।

This is where shree paraprasad beeja is hidden. **I want to know other such similar verses which describe other beeja like shrim,  kreem, hram,  hreem etc.**

Comment: For the construction of beeja mantra; check this answer: [Understanding the history and construction of beeja mantra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38825/647)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the history and construction of beeja mantra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/38820/understanding-the-history-and-construction-of-beeja-mantra)

Comment: @Proxy. the last line kinda looks similar so I asked. Still Anyways. It's Ok.  .